# Position of query word

Tags: python, nltk

I am currently working in python and using NLTK for features extraction of my data. One feature that I want to extract is position of a particular query word in a sentence. 
To achieve this, I tried

```
String.find(word)
```

But it gives me more words than the total number of words in the text.

Kindly suggest me some method to find the position of a particular word in the word.

For example "Today is my birthday" 
the position of word birthday is 4. How to go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = 'Today is my birthday'
string.find('my') #Out: 9
string[9:] #Out: 'my birthday'
```

`find` does not search string in terms of words but as characters. For simple examples you could do this (note that it's zero indexed):

```
words = string.split()
words.index('my') #Out: 2
```

**EDIT**

If you need a more sophisticated definition of a word than just strings separated by whitespace, you could use regular expresions. Here is a quick example:

```
import re
word_re = re.compile('\w+')
words = map(lambda match: match.group(0), word_re.finditer(string))
words.index('my') #Out: 2
```

**EDIT2**

```
try:
    words.index('earthquake')
except ValueError:
    print 'handle missing word here'
```

Comment: when i apply split it gives me error

 **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\workspace\test1\test1\final.py", line 36, in <module>
    fdist2=fdist1.split("earthquake")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'**

Comment: What is fdlist1? Use split on your original string of sentence. Then use index on result of that split.

Comment: Also split is used to split string on whitespace. index is the method that is used to find specific word in list of words.

Comment: How can i resolve this error? the Specific word is not present in the sentence.?
    **words1=words.index("earthquake" )**   
    **ValueError: 'earthquake' is not in list**

Comment: See additional edit.BTW. If I helped you please accept my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can transfert text to list of string using re or nltk, after you can search the world :

```
import re   
text = "Today is my birthday"
word = "birthday"
words1 = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split() # using re

import nltk
words2 = nltk.word_tokenize(text) # using nltk

position = 1
for str in words1 :# or for str in words2 :
   if str == word:
        print position
   position += 1
```

Comment: You need to change last line of your code `position + = 1` to `position += 1` as you can't insert  space between `+` and `=` in `Add AND` assignment operator. It will result in Syntax Error

Comment: Once you have the list `words2`, just get the position with `words2.index(word)`. (Also: Never use builtin names like `str` as variable names!)

Comment: Thanks alexis, if i use word2,  the line print will be :  print  words2.index(word) + 1